# Change the hostname using the batch script

Tags: batch-file

Hi i wanted to change the value of hostname for new computer but things didn't work as i try to input the value and getting the value for the hostname. I try to restart the computer the result is still the same.. I am testing to see whether this script is capable of updating the hostname for pcs or computer name

thanks

here is my code

```
REM This script runs in MS-DOS Batch File Language 

@echo off
set /p id= Enter ID or Hostname: 
echo %id%

WMIC computersystem where caption='%ComputerName%' rename %id%


REM exit the applications
echo "Export completed successfully. Press any key to exit"
pause >nul
exit /B
```

Comment: That code isn't bash at all -- it's Microsoft's batch language.

Comment: yup it is always running on batch

Comment: @DexterHo baSh and baTCh are very different. I've corrected the title and tag.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd probably do it:

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo Your current name is %ComputerName%

:AskID
Set "ID="
Set /P "ID=Enter your new name: "
If Not Defined ID (Echo Can not be empty
    GoTo AskID)
If /I "%ID%"=="%ComputerName%" Exit /B
If "%ID:~,1%"=="." (Echo Must not begin with a period
    GoTo AskID)

Rem Put here some more checks for disallowed words or characters


WMIC ComputerSystem Where Name="%ComputerName%" Call Rename "%ID%"
```

***Notes***

- This will need to be run 'As administrator'.
- The change will not take effect until the next reboot.
- It is important that you don't allow your end user, especially when running an administrative task to just enter anything at the prompt. Please consider following the `Rem`arked line's advice.

Comment: Nah not to worry they have user and password permission for domain user as they can't install batch file as part of policy.

Comment: The script has to be run 'As administrator', but it's your choice if you're happy for them to put in any name they want. Did you try it? It's working for me (tested on Windows Vista). _You may additionally add `>Nul 2>&1` to the end of the `WMIC` command line to suppress the output._

Comment: IT is.. I have to run via usb for 51 computers.. because of restrictions permission policy

Comment: 'IT is' what?, _working or being run as Administrator_.

Comment: Despite admitting to this answering your question, and after this reminder you returned here asking a new question. When reminded about this unaccepted solution you thought it best to delete your account instead. I trust that nobody shows you the same level of disrespect and rudness in the future. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the below batch script to change the windows 10 hostname through batch script and it work perfectly fine try it out and reboot the system atlast !

```
set /p NEW_NAME="Please enter computer name: "
for /f %%i in ('hostname') do set OLD_NAME=%%i
echo %OLD_NAME%
echo %NEW_NAME%
WMIC computersystem where caption="%OLD_NAME%" rename "%NEW_NAME%"
pause
```